# Merge sorted files on 2 columns

Tags: text-processing, sort

I want to merge some pre-sorted tab-delimited files:

- file `bygroup.0`:

  ```
  ancient-american    mercury 1   164
  ancient-american    mh25    2   8717664
  ancient-neolith tk11    262 40074321970
  ancientdna  jk21    6936    17069206689
  ancientdna  rm20    11267   372606702813
  ancientgen  ab34    1573    27800468142
  ancientgen  dg11    3516    45081427920
  ancientgen  fa8 7179    462396221983
  ancientgen  mp15    41  10248223517
  ancientgen  mp18    254 1049351143
  ancientgen  rm20    15100   1565340401
  ancientgen  tc9 1695    89861489631
  ```
- file `bygroup.2`:

  ```
  ancient-american    mercury 1   160
  ancient-american    mh25    2   10362712888
  ancient-neolith tk11    264 43842268110
  ancientdna  jk21    6919    16379509855
  ancientdna  rm20    11268   324906365415
  ancientgen  ab34    1577    33947364202
  ancientgen  dg11    3518    48092138390
  ancientgen  fa8 7174    472364587220
  ancientgen  mp15    39  32487920045
  ancientgen  mp18    254 1058177852
  ancientgen  rm20    15104   998615135
  ancientgen  tc9 1692    94858351562
  ```

You can see the 2 files have the same number of lines, and are in the same order based on columns 1 and 2, and the entries in those columns are the same.

Now I want to merge them so that all the lines with the same values in the first 2 columns are output sequentially.

I thought `sort -m` would be all I'd need, but:

```
$ sort -m bygroup.*
ancient-american    mercury 1   160
ancient-american    mercury 1   164
ancient-american    mh25    2   10362712888
ancient-american    mh25    2   8717664
ancient-neolith tk11    262 40074321970
ancientdna  jk21    6936    17069206689
ancientdna  rm20    11267   372606702813
ancientgen  ab34    1573    27800468142
ancientgen  dg11    3516    45081427920
ancientgen  fa8 7179    462396221983
ancientgen  mp15    41  10248223517
ancientgen  mp18    254 1049351143
ancientgen  rm20    15100   1565340401
ancientgen  tc9 1695    89861489631
ancient-neolith tk11    264 43842268110
ancientdna  jk21    6919    16379509855
ancientdna  rm20    11268   324906365415
ancientgen  ab34    1577    33947364202
ancientgen  dg11    3518    48092138390
ancientgen  fa8 7174    472364587220
ancientgen  mp15    39  32487920045
ancientgen  mp18    254 1058177852
ancientgen  rm20    15104   998615135
ancientgen  tc9 1692    94858351562
```

(I get the same results with other options I added, eg. `sort -k 1,2 -ifm`.)

It does what I expected for ancient-american, but not for the others. What's going on, and is there another fast and efficient way of doing this without resorting to a full sort (`sort` works without the `-m` here).

Comment: Maybe it's the locale? Try `LC_COLLATE=C sort -m bygroup.*` or with `LC_ALL=C`

Comment: Thanks @rowboat, `LC_COLLATE=C` worked. Make your comment an answer and I'll accept. (I can't just `paste` because the full set of data files don't always have all the same entries.)

Answer (score 1):

TXR Lisp solution:

```
$ txr merge.tl 
ancient-american    mercury 1   164
ancient-american    mercury 1   160
ancient-american    mh25    2   8717664
ancient-american    mh25    2   10362712888
ancient-neolith tk11    262 40074321970
ancient-neolith tk11    264 43842268110
ancientdna  jk21    6936    17069206689
ancientdna  jk21    6919    16379509855
ancientdna  rm20    11267   372606702813
ancientdna  rm20    11268   324906365415
ancientgen  ab34    1573    27800468142
ancientgen  ab34    1577    33947364202
ancientgen  dg11    3516    45081427920
ancientgen  dg11    3518    48092138390
ancientgen  fa8 7179    462396221983
ancientgen  fa8 7174    472364587220
ancientgen  mp15    41  10248223517
ancientgen  mp15    39  32487920045
ancientgen  mp18    254 1049351143
ancientgen  mp18    254 1058177852
ancientgen  rm20    15100   1565340401
ancientgen  rm20    15104   998615135
ancientgen  tc9 1695    89861489631
ancientgen  tc9 1692    94858351562
```

Code:

```
(defstruct record ()
  key
  line
  (:method equal (me) me.key))

(defun read-recs (file)
  (build
    (awk (:set fs "\t")
         (:inputs file)
         (t (add (new record
                      key [f 0..2]
                      line rec))))))

(mapdo [chain .line put-line] (merge (read-recs "bygroup.0") (read-recs "bygroup.1")))
```

For holding the information from each record of the file, we define a `record` structure type which holds a `key`, our sort key and a `line`, which is the original verbatim line. The `key` slot will be a list of two strings.

The `record` type has an `equal` method, which implements [equality substitution](https://www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#N-02CDB347). This means that whenever a `record` object is compared by the functions `equal`, `less` or `greater`, the value of that method is taken in place of the object. For instance, if we were to `sort` a list of `record` structures, without specifying a comparison function, they will sort according to the key.

The function `read-recs` reads the specified file with the help of `awk`. A field separator is specified as `"\t" (tab). For each record, the` t`condition (unconditional truth) dispatches an action which creates a record object. The`key`is a sublist of the`f`(field) list, consisting of the first two fields. The`line`is the`rec`: the whole record.` rec`is like`$0` in standard Awk.

The `build` macro is for implicit, procedural list construction. For instance `(build (add 1) (add 2))` will return the list `(1 2)`. `build` creates a scope in which `add` calls add to an implicit, hidden list, which is returned when `build` terminates.

Having `read-recs` and a `record` type properly keyed on the desired key via equality substitution, all we have to do is read the two files, and hand them to the `merge` function to get the sorted list.

The `record` objects in this list are then mapped through a chaining of two functions: `[chain .line put-line]`: the `.line` function retrieves the `line` slot of the object, which is then handed to `put-line` that dumps it to standard output, followed by a newline.

---

An alternative implementation of the `read-recs` function without `build` and `awk` might be:

```
(defun read-recs (file)
  (collect-each ((line (file-get-lines file)))
    (let ((fields (spl #\tab line)))
      (new record key [fields 0..2]
                  line line))))
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using the R-programming language**

Text files were saved and one-or-more space characters were replaced with single tabs. The two data files were read into R:

```
> group0 <- read.delim("/Users/admin/bygroup.0", header=FALSE)
> group2 <- read.delim("/Users/admin/bygroup.2", header=FALSE)
> head(group0)
                V1      V2    V3           V4
1 ancient-american mercury     1          164
2 ancient-american    mh25     2      8717664
3  ancient-neolith    tk11   262  40074321970
4       ancientdna    jk21  6936  17069206689
5       ancientdna    rm20 11267 372606702813
6       ancientgen    ab34  1573  27800468142
> head(group2)
                V1      V2    V3           V4
1 ancient-american mercury     1          160
2 ancient-american    mh25     2  10362712888
3  ancient-neolith    tk11   264  43842268110
4       ancientdna    jk21  6919  16379509855
5       ancientdna    rm20 11268 324906365415
6       ancientgen    ab34  1577  33947364202
```

To merge the data files, use R's `merge()` function:

```
> merge(group0, group2, by = c("V1","V2"))
                 V1      V2  V3.x         V4.x  V3.y         V4.y
1  ancient-american mercury     1          164     1          160
2  ancient-american    mh25     2      8717664     2  10362712888
3   ancient-neolith    tk11   262  40074321970   264  43842268110
4        ancientdna    jk21  6936  17069206689  6919  16379509855
5        ancientdna    rm20 11267 372606702813 11268 324906365415
6        ancientgen    ab34  1573  27800468142  1577  33947364202
7        ancientgen    dg11  3516  45081427920  3518  48092138390
8        ancientgen     fa8  7179 462396221983  7174 472364587220
9        ancientgen    mp15    41  10248223517    39  32487920045
10       ancientgen    mp18   254   1049351143   254   1058177852
11       ancientgen    rm20 15100   1565340401 15104    998615135
12       ancientgen     tc9  1695  89861489631  1692  94858351562
```

Data can be written back out again using either `write.delim()` or `write.csv()` functions. For help, type the command at the prompt preceded by a question-mark, as in `?getwd()`, `?setwd()`, `?read.delim()` or `?merge()`.

*[Note: depending on the age of your R-installation, you may have to include the parameter `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` to each of your `read.delim()` function calls].*

https://www.r-project.org/
https://cran.r-project.org/index.html